# Scrollable tab content with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Within a fixed-height container, I'd like to make the tab content scroll, leaving the tabs at the top.

```
<div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs" style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid black">

    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        ...     
    </ul>

    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        This is long and must scroll, tabs must stay on top
        ....
    </div>

</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/graemian/Wxr9d/3/

I've found a solution using the flex layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/graemian/wefPL/1/

(Chrome-only), but surely there is another, simpler way?

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate scroll with overflow:auto

```
.bs-example{
   position: relative;
}

.tab-pane{
   position: absolute;
   top: 42px;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Very clever! Is there any way to get around the fixed "42px"?

Comment: you can add simply `height: 180px; overflow: auto;` to the `.tab-pane`  block,  where 180px = height of .bs-example  - height of .nav-tabs. and remove styles such as position: absoulte and other